# linux: how do I generate a core file?

Tags: c, linux, core-file

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.  I run "ulimit -c 999" then I compile and execute (`gcc test.c && ./a.out`) this tiny app:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main( void )
{
    raise( SIGSEGV );

    return 0;
}
```

Even though this does print a "Segmentation fault" message, I don't see a core file.  What have I missed that is preventing the core file from being generated?

Comment: `ulimit -c unlimited` first - then call `kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);`

Comment: Isn't raise() the same as kill(getpid())?  And as you can see from my question, I'm already calling ulimit.

Comment: `raise` is not exactly the same. `kill` targets the whole process while `raise` targets the thread that called `raise`. Also, `kill` is specified to give `si_code` of `SI_USER` when the signal is delivered, while `raise` may generate a different code (on Linux it generates `SI_TKILL`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

More about enabling core dumps [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_enable_core.html)

EDIT:

Ok, I see what is the problem. Your core file limit is too low. 999 bytes (as you set it) is not enough. Increase it to something reasonable. unlimited is the best parameter.

Comment: @Stéphane Ok, edited answer. Your option for ulimit is too low

Comment: Anything more than 999 produces the error "Operation not permitted". Followed your link and increased the limit as root. Now it works as expected, test app is logging `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  Note the limit is in KB.  So 999 means 999KB.  I've now run tests with limits of just 9, and all my cores are 8KB in size.  (Most likely unusable at that size, but that is a different topic.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ulimit` command with the `-c` flag to control the maximum size of core file you want to allow.

Comment: In the mad rush to answer this question, I think everyone has missed the first sentence where I wrote that I am calling ulimit.

Comment: I think the issue is the limit size you have specified; have you tried `unlimited` as suggested by other answers?

Comment: $ ulimit -c unlimited
bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Regardless, in the case where I want to use it I don't want unlimited.  I need to truncate the core size if necessary due to very limited disk space.

Comment: OK, you'll need to be root to set unlimited core file size and most importantly truncated core files have no purpose at all.  Therefore the issue seems to be to find a size that you are allowed to set as a non-root user and a size that is large enough to hold the core so it can be debugged.

Comment: Do not assume truncated core files have no purpose.  If you have large amounts of ram allocated in your application (say 50GB) your core files will be huge.  Limiting the size, you can still gather some information from the cores while preventing absolutely huge files filling up limited disk space.  In some situations -- such as the one I was facing -- this can be a great help.